# Can bazel built debs be uploaded to PPAs?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, bazel, deb, launchpad

Using bazel's built in [pkg_deb](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/pkg.html#pkg_deb) rule, I've created a debian package.
  I'd like to upload this deb file to my [PPA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas), but I have found that to be challenging.

As far as I can tell,  bazel creates "binary debian packages" which are not allowed for PPAs.  Instead I must convert it to a "source debian package".  Doing so is not obvious to me.  The examples I've found online show very simple projects with a Makefile tailored to meet the needs of Ubuntu's launchpad.  When you upload something to a PPA, I think it gets built in a sand-boxed environment (Part of this ["reproducible builds"](https://reproducible-builds.org/) initiative I guess).

I'm looking for the simplest way to upload debian files built out of bazel.  Since bazel abstracts a lot of the details of building through rules, its unclear to me whether I could convert this to some kind of Makefile-- or if there is a way I could avoid this entirely.

Does anyone have any experience building debs with bazel and uploading them to PPAs?  Or more generically,  taking a binary debian package and making it a source debian package to meet the requirements of PPAs?

I think I'll have to write a custom rule similar to what the bazel project is doing:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/e67c961905792cd63950c6f6efc33275ad243c49/scripts/packages/debian/BUILD#L119, but it will be hard to come up with a compile command that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

A PPA can do whatever it wants, as there are no rules on what can go into a PPA.  Debian's package repository has [rules for upstream sources](https://wiki.debian.org/UpstreamGuide), which include no binary blobs.  The ideal way to handle this is would be to have `apt` pull in Bazel when building from source, but as of mid 2020 [Bazel can't be used in Debian upstream either](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=782654#139).